# iOS. Using music to generate game levels

Tags: ios

Is it possible to generate game levels using music without of violation of Apple's rules for applications in app store

Comment: What do you mean specifically?

Comment: simply omg again. Why can I ask about apple app store rules? But I know how to avoid there strange rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and many apps do this, an example would be "Beat Hazards". and there is no reason to believe it would violate the tos.